# Cannot read property of null (reading 'contains')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to test out the following code snippet in the browsers console:

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('w-48');

const handleClick = (event) => {
  if (dropdown.contains(event.target)) {
    console.log('Inside dropdown');
  } else {
    console.log('OUTSIDE Dropdown');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
```

The component for the Dropdown itself looks like so:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { GoChevronDown, GoChevronLeft } from "react-icons/go";
import Panel from "./Panel";

function Dropdown({ options, value, onChange }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleOptionClick = (option) => {
    // CLOSE DROPDOWN
    setIsOpen(false);
    // WHAT OPTION DID THE USER CLICK ON??
    onChange(option);
  };

  const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    return (
      <div
        className='hover:g-sky-100 rounded cursor-pointer p-1'
        onClick={() => handleOptionClick(option)}
        key={option.value}
      >
        {option.label}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className='w-48 relative'>
      <Panel
        className='flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer'
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {value?.label || "Select..."}
        {isOpen ? (
          <GoChevronDown className='text-3xl' />
        ) : (
          <GoChevronLeft className='text-3xl' />
        )}
      </Panel>
      {isOpen && <Panel className='absolute top-full'>{renderedOptions}</Panel>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

But as soon as I tried to open the dropdown, I got the following error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contains') TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of null (reading 'contains')
> at HTMLDocument.handleClick (:4:16)

My expectation was to see a console log of `inside dropdown`.

Comment: `document.querySelector('w-48')` looks for a `<w-48>` element in your document. If it returns `null` that means there is no such element.

Comment: Should be `document.querySelector('.w-48')`

Comment: `className='hover:g-sky-100 rounded cursor-pointer p-1'` seems like an odd class name there at the start.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's Tailwind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `.` in front of `w-48` and put `?` in front of `.contains(event.target)`.

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.w-48');

const handleClick = (event) => {
  if (dropdown?.contains(event.target)) {
    console.log('Inside dropdown');
  } else {
    console.log('OUTSIDE Dropdown');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your class variable in iffi like this and then use it

```
let dropdown

(() => {
 dropdown = document.querySelector('.w-48');
})()
```

also one highlight in your code you are missing (".") in front of class in querySelector classes should be accessed with (".") and ids with ("#")
in querySelector

here we are using iffi as iffi's are immediately invoked function's which loads before the browser's first paint on screen.

Comment: There is no benefit to using an IIFE here at all.

Comment: @Shubham, if you just post an answer that says I am missing the dot for a class name or a hash for id, that should suffice.